# Without losing the parentheses, convert list to set and then "join" together with a list of sets

Tags: python, set

- I have an index value called `new_c[a]`. `new_c[a] == [1,2,3]`
- I have a list of sets called `check_com_of_three`. Which is `[(4,5,6), (7,8,9)]`.
- I would like to join `set(new_c[a])` with `check_com_of_three`.

(eg. `[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]`)

I'm using set to make sure there are no repeating sets in `set(check_com_of_three)`

```
>>>set(new_c[a]) + str(',') + set(check_com_of_three)
```

### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    set(new_c[a]) + str(',') + set(check_com_of_three)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'str'
```

Any explanation as to why I'm doing this wrong, and what is the best and easiest method to do this?

Comment: What is an index?

Comment: @Dani Mesejo The location of a value in a list.

Comment: Does your end result need to be a set, a list of sets, a list of tuples, or a string?

Comment: The error message is because you can't normally mix types with the `+` operator.

Comment: @luther I believe it needs to be tuples. Perhaps I'm confusing tuples and sets.

Comment: A tuple is basically an immutable list. A set is an unordered group of unique values. Perhaps you're just using sets to validate your data somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a list, you can use `insert` with an index position:

```
x = (1,2,3)
y = [(4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

y.insert(0, tuple(x))
print(y)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not completely sure what you need, but this should show you how the `+` operator works. Both operands of `+` must have the same type, and the result will be the same type as both operands, in this case, `list`.

```
element = new_c[a]
check_com_of_three = [(4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

new_list = check_com_of_three + [element]
```